# How to load a Keras-trained model from Python in C #?

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio, tensorflow, keras

I use the Keras.NET package, to load my trained model (using Keras in Python, saved in a .pb or .h5 file), as shown in the figure below.

[Code to Load Trained Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrbfr.png)

The model prediction has been working perfectly for a while, however, as it is a real-time analytics application it runs full-time. But after a runtime, the application is no longer able to use the loaded model. Introducing errors like: Exception thrown: 'System.AccessViolationException' in Python.Runtime.dll or

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgNkl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this... https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/595

This person had a similar issue and I think they fixed it. If the method they used did not work, there are a few others listed as links in some of the responses.